# Notification Mail based on Storage Usage in salesforce

Tags: user, data-storage

Have one question that is it possible in production to send notification mail or generate task whenever usage storage is crossed the 80%.

Can i need to write a class for that or any standard functionality was there ?

Actually i just want to be alert whenever production data storage reached at 80%.

Thanks in Advanced for your support.....

Answer (score 1):

Its currently not possible to get the data usage via the API or via Apex so unfortunately you will have to check the system overview every now and then.

And vote for one of the ideas on this, e.g.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l1phAAA